# Find minimum and maximum given $x+y+z = 10$ and $x^2+y^2+z^2 = 36 $.

Tags: real-analysis, optimization

Given
$$ x+y+z = 10\\x^2+y^2+z^2 = 36 $$
find maximum and minimum value of $xyz$.

Using the relation A.M $\ge$ G.M it is possible to find maximum value as $ \frac{x+y+z}{3} \ge \sqrt[3]{xyz}$, but I have problem with finding minimum value, because harmonic mean isn't really helpful here. I think Lagrange multiplier may also be a solution but I'm curious if there's any easier option here.

Comment: For those trying out this problem, you can use [this functionality](https://www.geogebra.org/3d/dqqum8cn)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the first equation, $$x^2+y^2+z^2+2(xy+yz+zx)=100$$

From this equation, subtract the second equation, so we are left with,
$$2(xy+yz+zx)=64\\(xy+yz+zx)=32$$

Thus let x,y,z be the roots of the cubic eq P(a)=0 ,using vieta's theorem

$$a^3−10a^2+32a−p=0$$ where $p=xyz$.

Now you can find the maxima and minima of $a^3−10a^2+32a$ and hence  $p$. Apparently, the maxima and minima come out to be infinitely large. Why?

This is because, the domain of $a$ is such that we consider complex value of the variables named $(x,y,z)$. For the real values of the variables, it will only exist when $\dfrac{dp}{da}\leq 0$ (in other words we find the local extremas). Differentiating and equating to zero for $a^3−10a^2+32a$ gives us,
$$3a^2−20a+32=0$$ and the roots $a=\frac{8}{3}, 4$. Which further yields the maximum and minimum for the real domain as $32$ and $33.185$. You can verify this yourself following [this](https://www.geogebra.org/3d/dqqum8cn).

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

*For positive* $x,y,z$

$$(x+y+z)^2=x^2+y^2+z^2+2(xy+yz+xz)$$
$$\implies (xy+yz+xz)=32$$

### FOR MAXIMUM

Use AM $\ge GM$
$$xy+yz+xz \ge 3(xyz)^{\frac{2}{3}}$$

Comment: how are you sure that any of xy,yz,zx is not negative

Comment: Its obvious. OP hasnt mentioned it, but he tried with AM GM inequality. So I assume it is positive?

Comment: OP could be wrong, they mentioned lagrange multipliers as well

Comment: In that case, Ill add a note

Comment: That's actually a good point, there's no assumption about x,y,z being positive, so AM>GM>HM can't really solve that problem - thanks!

Comment: I have no expertise in Lagrange multipliers. So I'll just provide my answer for them being positive

Comment: PS, I say you prove it is positive always, a graphical calc might help.

Comment: You couldnt find the minima using amgmhm

Comment: @Art3 we can use am-gm in case of $x^2+y^2+z^2=36$

Comment: The maximum value yielded be these equations can never be attained (34.84). The max is 33.18 and min is 32...it is very tight